# Django 2, Celery 4.1 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named djcelery

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I am running into a ModuleNotFound error using Django and Celery. I have a post endpoint using django rest framework that runs a celery task to parse and store json. I can serve pages fine, but when I do a post I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /app/v1/results
Exception Value: No module named 'djcelery'
```

At first I thought that maybe I had a versioning issue, so I checked my packages, but I'm on the latest and don't see any outstanding conflicts. I do see the djcelery is reference in the loaders **init**.py of the celery projects:

[https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/loaders/**init**.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/loaders/__init__.py)

```
amqp (2.2.2)
billiard (3.5.0.3)
celery (4.1.0)
certifi (2018.1.18)
Django (2.0.3)
django-celery-results (1.0.1)
django-filter (1.1.0)
django-pyodbc-azure (2.0.3.0)
djangorestframework (3.7.7)
kombu (4.1.0)
Markdown (2.6.11)
mod-wsgi (4.6.2)
pip (9.0.1)
pyodbc (4.0.22)
pytz (2018.3)
setuptools (38.5.1)
vine (1.1.4)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

My project follows the core of the Django first steps http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps:

```
Proj
 - proj
   - __init__.py
   - celeryapp.py
   - settings.py
   - urls.py
 - app
   - models.py
   - tasks.py
   - views.py
   - urls.py
 - manage.py
```

For all of my code I started with what was in the first steps tutorial, but have made a few changes running into issues and finding post as well as trying to find where I might be importing incorrectly relative to the `NotFoundError`. I have also added the `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals` to all files in the project. 
In my `settings.py` I have:

```
 # Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672/proj_host'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

In celeryapp.py (renamed from celery.py due to import errors and other post on the issue) I have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from django import apps
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object(settings)

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}', format(self.request))
```

And in my `__init__.py` I have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celeryapp import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Finally `views.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import json
from app.tasks import process_json_result
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class AppResultView(APIView):
    #check for errors then
    process_json_result.delay(json.dumps(request.data))
    return Response({"success": True, "message": "Ok", "payload": ""})
```

and `tasks.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import json
import logging
from proj.celeryapp import app
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from app.models import Result

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


@app.task(name="app.tasks.process_json_result")
def process_json_result(result):
    logger.info("Processing result")
    py_result = json.loads(result)
    # processing occurs
```

And the longer traceback from the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /app/v1/results
No module named 'djcelery'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://testdeployserver/app/v1/results
Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Executable: 
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path: ['/var/www/python/proj', '/var/www/python/proj/proj', '/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python36.zip', '/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6', '/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 23:00:10 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_celery_results']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py" in _get_current_object
  317.             return object.__getattribute__(self, '__thing')

During handling of the above exception ('PromiseProxy' object has no attribute '__thing'), another exception occurred:

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py" in __get__
  42.             return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]

During handling of the above exception ('data'), another exception occurred:

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py" in __get__
  42.             return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]

During handling of the above exception ('loader'), another exception occurred:

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/python/proj/app/views.py" in post
  24.             process_app_result.delay(json.dumps(request.data))

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py" in __getattr__
  146.         return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py" in _get_current_object
  319.             return self.__evaluate__()

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py" in __evaluate__
  349.             thing = Proxy._get_current_object(self)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py" in _get_current_object
  109.             return loc(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in _task_from_fun
  462.             task.bind(self)  # connects task to this app

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in bind
  320.                 setattr(cls, attr_name, conf[config_name])

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py" in __getitem__
  431.                 return getitem(k)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py" in __getitem__
  280.                 return mapping[_key]

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py" in __getitem__
  987.         if key in self.data:

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py" in __get__
  44.             value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in data
  148.         return self.callback()

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in _finalize_pending_conf
  911.         conf = self._conf = self._load_config()

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in _load_config
  921.             self.loader.config_from_object(self._config_source)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py" in __get__
  44.             value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in loader
  1209.         return get_loader_cls(self.loader_cls)(app=self)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/__init__.py" in get_loader_cls
  21.     return symbol_by_name(loader, LOADER_ALIASES, imp=import_from_cwd)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py" in symbol_by_name
  56.             module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py" in import_from_cwd
  101.         return imp(module, package=package)

File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _gcd_import
  994. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _find_and_load
  971. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _find_and_load_unlocked
  941. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _call_with_frames_removed
  219. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _gcd_import
  994. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _find_and_load
  971. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _find_and_load_unlocked
  953. <source code not available>

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /app/v1/results
Exception Value: No module named 'djcelery'
```

The pathing on the traceback appears correct pulling from the Apache/mod_wsgi anaconda environment path, and I see the celery package files in my anaconda virtualenvironment, so not sure what isn't being resolved correctly or if my task path isn't setup just right for Celery.

Comment: I can feel your pain. I do not answer to your question because I have a suggestion and not an answer. Maybe you should consider to follow my steps, I left celery behind long time ago after months of struggling and I adopted django-q. See the docs here: django-q.readthedocs.io

Comment: you need add `djcelery` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: I thought that was prior to celery 4.1.0? I'll give that a try, but I don't see it in the django celery docs or github django example.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/django/proj/settings.py

Comment: What Ykh suggest does not work in fact it causes the application to fail out earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came back to the problem this morning and rolled back all my changes until I lined up with the Django First steps documentation. At that point I ran into the `cannot import Celery from celery` issue that I've seen others post about. That got me wondering why this worked on the django test server, but not on my deployment server. I then went to look at the httpd conf file for Apache and found what I thought might be causing the issue:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess proj python-path=/var/www/python:/var/www/python/proj:/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I wondered if my project being before my packages on the path was causing the issue so I changed this to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess proj python-path=//home/alex/anaconda3/envs/clean_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages:var/www/python:/var/www/python/proj
```

And my project is now deployed to Apache with Celery running as expected.

TLDR check your pathing and any difference between path resolution on your django test server and deployment server. Make sure packages are before your app in your path especially with Celery in the mix.